# Updating MySQL Fields

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I am trying to update certain fields where the username is from a php page. I can get it to connect to my database but my code structure is just wrong.. I have been trying a bunch of ways.. Maybe someone could give me some insight. I have a form.php that the person enters the information, it sends the information to $keydet.

I want it to Update the table `etest in Database`ko Where `Name is equal to what they put in for username. Then update the values in Columns; Points, MGP, Money, Attributes, VotsPoints. with the values they submitted.

This was my best attempt.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Updatet</title>
</head>

<body><?php
$link = mysql_connect("IP", "User", "Password") or die(mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db("ko", $link) or die (mysql_error());

$ad = $_POST['username'];
$cp = $_POST['cps'];
$mg = $_POST['mgp'];
$mon = $_POST['money'];
$att = $_POST['att'];
$mgv = $_POST['mgv'];

$kaydet = mysql_query("UPDATE etest WHERE Name = $ad (Points, MGP, Money, Attributes, VotsPoints) values ('$cp', '$mg','$mon','$att','$mgv')") or die("Update Failed");
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Anyone got some advice? Thanks in advanced!

Comment: dont forget the apostrophes enclosing string types

Comment: dont forget the escaping and sanitation of the input data

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Learn the UPDATE syntax manual.

`UPDATE table SET column1 = 'value1', column2 = 'value2' WHERE column_id = $id`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

---

These kind of question you can solve by yourself by setting the proper error mode, in your case you have set up a predefined error, but not the original mysql_error. In case of original mysql error, it will return you an error like "You have an error in your MySQL syntax near 'WHERE...' check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server", so you would understand you have a syntax error, and simply can google "MYSQL UPDATE"